# Problem with [] operator in doubly linked list c++

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I'm a real beginner at c++ and I have been added a task to write an stl-like doubly-linked list with basic methods and operators. So I have made some basic methods but it prints "Segmentation fault" error after compiling the code when I use [ ] operator. I will be happy to receive some help with solving this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Node
{
    public:
        T data;
        Node *prev;
        Node *next;
        Node(T data, Node *prev = nullptr, Node *next = nullptr): data(data), prev(prev), next(next) {}

};

template<typename T>
class List
{
    public:
        T& operator[](T const index);
        List();
        List(const List&);
        ~List();
        bool empty();
        int size();
        void clear();
        void push_back(T data);
        void push_front(T data);
        void pop_back();
        void pop_front();
        void resize(int nums);
    private:
        int Size;
        Node<T> *tail;
        Node<T> *head;
};

template<typename T>
List<T>::List()
{
    Size = 0;
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
List<T>::List(const List & L)
{
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    int count = 0; 
    Node<T> *temp = head;
    while(temp)
    {
        push_back(temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

template<typename T>
List<T>::~List()
{
    Node<T> *temp;
    while(head)
    {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

template<typename T>
T & List<T>::operator[](T const index)
{
    Node<T> *curr = head;
    int counter = 0;
    while (curr)
    {
        if (counter == index)
        {
            return curr->data;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
        counter++;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::push_back(T data)
{
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head =  new Node<T>(data, tail, nullptr);
    }
    if (tail != nullptr)
    {
        tail->next = new Node<T>(data, tail, nullptr);
    }
    tail = new Node<T>(data, tail, nullptr);
    ++Size;

}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::push_front(T data)
{
    head = new Node<T>(data, nullptr, head);
    Size++;
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::pop_back()
{
    Node<T> *temp = tail;
    tail = tail->prev;
    delete temp;
    Size--;
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::pop_front()
{
    Node<T> *temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete temp;
    Size--;
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::clear()
{
    while (Size)
    {
        pop_back();
    }
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::resize(int num)
{
    if (num > Size)
    {
        while (Size != num)
        {
            push_back(0);
        }
    }
    else{
        while (Size != num)
        {
            pop_back();
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
bool List<T>::empty() {return Size == 0;}

template<typename T>
int List<T>::size() {return Size;}

int main()
{
    List<int> l;
    l.push_back(1234);
    l.push_back(124);
    l.push_back(10);
    l.push_front(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<l[i]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by learning to use a debugger.

Comment: Unrelated: Since a linked list is not a random access data structure (you can't go from 0 to 10 without visiting all of the nodes between them) what's the point of having operator `[]`?

Comment: Compiler might also help here. It should be warning about a path without a `return`.

Comment: Also, you're missing copy assignment operators, which means you're violating the rule-of-three

Comment: @eerorika that's a bit harsh. the guy said he was a beginner and he has obviously put effort into this. you can cut him some slack and be nicer.

Comment: There's at least one bug in `push_back`. I would guess that creates invalid data, causing `operator[]` to crash

Comment: Your copy constructor, `push_back()`, and `push_front()` are all implemented wrong. And your `operator[]`, `pop_back()`, and `pop_front()` are not doing bounds checking. And the return value of `operator[]` is undefined if the specified index is invalid.

Comment: Some of the best advice you can give a beginner is to get a good grip on debugger use.  It's probably the second best programmer productivity tool out there, sitting right after the compiler. Figuring out turbo debugger early on, before I got to university, is probably the only reason I still had time to run AD&D games while in university.

Comment: @user4581301 i agree that it's an excellent advice. my issue is not with the content, but with how it is delivered.

Comment: When it comes to graph structures like a linked list, the best way to figure out what's going on, debugger included, is to visualize the problem by drawing pictures.

Comment: @obe `the guy said he was a beginner` That's in fact why learning to use the debugger is the next step to take. `be nicer.` Do you have a suggestion on how to re-phrase my advice?

Comment: "Hi, @timaracov, the issue is quite likely an access out of bound. If you use a debugger, you can run your code line by line. It will even tell you which line it crashed on. I believe, on MSVC, you can start it with F5, but it's different in other IDEs"

Comment: @eerorika i would just write it a bit softer. like "I am not sure what the specific problem in your code is, but I recommend to learn how to use a debugger. It would be an excellent time investment for this and for future issues."

Comment: I think the best way to put the point across to the beginner is to tell him what we would use to solve his issue.  Unless the program is a toy program, most here would use the debugger to answer coding questions.  In many cases, the debugger is our "answer giver" here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Fleshing that a bit more, the "answer giver" is the looking-glass the debugger provides that allows you to take the line provided by the error message and look into the operation of the code at that specific point to see what caused the error to be generated -- giving you the answer to your coding problem.

Comment: How to use a debugger: Place a breakpoint at the start of the area of code you wish to inspect (and if you have no better idea, this is usually the start of `main`), then step through the code keeping an eye on the path the program takes and the values of the variables in play. When you see something unexpected, stop. That's a bug or an error in your expectations. You need to fix either. When you're sure your expectations are correct, restart the program and step through the event leading up to the bug a few times gathering information. Use the information to develop a solution.

Comment: Note that one of the pains of global variables is they can cause things to happen BEFORE `main`. This makes bugs involving them a lot harder to track down. That by itself is a good reason to avoid global variables as much as possible.

Comment: T& operator[](T const index); the signature is odd, the index should be an integral type (size_t for instance) not T

Answer (score 1):

```
if (tail != nullptr)
{
    tail->next = new Node<T>(data, tail, nullptr);
}
tail = new Node<T>(data, tail, nullptr);
```

This is your biggest error. You add `next` after `tail`, but then you set `tail` to something different. So, next time you push, you will push to the new `tail`, not to the chains of `next`s starting from the `head`. As a result, your list is shorter than expected, and you traverse it past the end.

You probably want something like: (not tested)

```
if (tail != nullptr)
{
    tail->next = new Node<T>(data, tail, nullptr);
    tail = tail->next;
}
else
{
    tail = new Node<T>(data, tail, nullptr);
}
```

Comment: This can be simplified further: `Node *n = new Node<T>(data, tail, nullptr); if (!head) { head = n; } if (tail) { tail->next = n; } tail = n;`

Comment: Note to Remy's comment. If head and tail members are properly maintained, `if (tail)` can be replaced with `else` .